# popBackStack with Pass Parse Object

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an `Activity A`. `Activity A` calls fragment `frag1`. `frag1` calls fragment `frag2`. Lastly `frag2` calls `frag3`.

When I click on a button in `frag3`, I want to call `frag1`, pass and parse an object from `frag3` to `frag1`. I tried to do this with an object bundle sent from `frag3` to `frag1`.

I see that there is a `popBackStack()` method. However, I am a little confused on how this would work. Is it safe to use this method?

I do not know how to do it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some people recomends to Use Otro or Event Bus. But i think is better to Use your own callbacks (interfaces) and handle that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use Local Broadcast for this.

write Broadcast receiver on fragment 1,

On apply button of fragment 3, broadcast your data , and then pop fragment 3

example-

```
private final BroadcastReceiver myLocalBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
           ;

            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

            if (bundle != null) {

             get data from bundle



            }



    };
```

on fragment 3(apply button):

```
      Intent localBroadcastIntent = new Intent(Constant.MY_ACTION);


        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.put("your data);

        localBroadcastIntent.putExtras(bundle);

        LocalBroadcastManager myLocalBroadcastManager =           LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity());
        myLocalBroadcastManager.sendBroadcast(localBroadcastIntent);





        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Event Bus pattern for passing data(events) between fragments. Then work with you fragment stack in usual way.

There are several popular libraries that implement event bus. I personally prefer

- [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)
- [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/)

Comment: thanks for your valuable answer. EventBus work for me. please like question because i can not able to like your question.